# Convert `int` to `bool` in if condition in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

In Python 3.x, in an `if` condition, should I convert an `int` into a `bool` if I want to do something only when the `int` is zero, or is it just sufficient to use the `int` as-is?

```
# Option 1 - convert i to a bool in the if condition
def fun(i)
    if bool(i):
        # do something

# Option 2 - just use i in the if condition
def fun(i)
    if i:
        # do something

i = 0
fun(i)

i = int(some_mathematical_operation(i))
fun(i)
```

Comment: There is no need to convert the int to a bool, 0 is considered false, and every other value is true.

Comment: `if bool(i):` is equivalent to `if i:`. There is no need for an explicit conversion.

Comment: Arguably, if you logically mean "if not zero", then you could use `if i != 0:` to be more explicit, but never use `if bool(i):` which is both needlessly slow and adds no information to the logical intent of the test over `if i:`.